# sign dynemic key.value in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to assign a dynamic object value named destination inside ngFor like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of object.destination"><p [innerHTML]="cont.disc"></p> </div>
```

This destination is supposed to change dynamically using property binding (it works)

In my component.ts there is a function which assigns the dynamic value I get to the destination value, and connect it to the object key:

```
 public getDestination() {
 this.destination = this.to;
 return (this.destination = `${this.content}.${this.destination}`);  }
```

But all I get is that {{ object.destination }} equal to

```
<p>[object Object].india</p>
```

How can I make the object value dynamic so it will change depending on the property binding?

Comment: well if you want to display an object use <p>{{objectName | json}}</p> but why do you want to display the object ? or am i misunderstanding the question?

Comment: to get rid of [object Object], you have to print each attribute separately or try with `json` pipe?

Comment: the output is  a json data contain information 
which varies according to geographic location.

Comment: the json pipe was the first thing tried. didnt work

Comment: why `object.description instead` of just `description`?  => `let obj of destination`

Comment: Also be aware that anything that goes into [InnerHTML] attribute needs to be sanitised using the DOMSanitiser https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer or it won't work

Comment: destination is the value i'm trying to assign to an object key. not the object it self

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve